# Running maven commands in directory where pom.xml is not present

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to execute a maven command from directory where I am currently without moving to directory where pom.xml is present. Is there any way to do so? Assume that I am currently in sub-directory of directory where pom.xml is present.

I tried searching same and I came up with below solution:

Using `mvn -f`  : In this I need to provide the path of pom.xml which doesn't meets my requirement.

Please suggest if this can be done.

Comment: What kind of command would you like to execute?

Comment: for ex. mvn clean install

Comment: Than you need a pom file in this directory. Otherwise it does not make really sense.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Exactly! this is what I want. If pom is not present in current directory it should pick up pom xml present in the root directory

Comment: In which root directory ?